# jQuery reset count on key press after partial postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a `TextBox` inside an asp.net `UpdatePanel` that records the number of key presses with some jquery

```
$(document).on("keypress", "#TextBox",function()   {
    $("#KeyPressCount").val(i += 1);
});
```

I do a partial postback after a button click inside the UpdatePanel and the jquery re-binds as expected and continues counting the key presses.

Now if I wanted to reset the count after the partial postback how would I go about doing that?

So if it had counted 20 key presses then a postback occurred it would reset to 0 and start counting again.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var keyPresses = 0;

$(document).on("keypress", "#TextBox",function()   {
    $("#KeyPressCount").val(keyPresses += 1);
});
```

Now all you need to do is update the value of keyPresses to 0 in the function that performs the postback.

Comment: Thanks, I update the keyPresses var to 0 after postback and works as I would like.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
$(document).on("keypress", "#TextBox",function()   { 
    var $keypress = $("#KeyPressCount");
    // if i==20 the set it to 0 or else add 1       
    $keypress.val($keypress.val() >= 20 ? 0 : $keypress.val() += 1);
});
```